# Jquery change id dynamicallly and keep functionality of original id

Tags: jquery, function, replace, identifier, svg-edit

I need to change the ID of element in jquery. This I make with following code:

```
$('#tool_fhpath').attr('id', 'tool_fhpath2');
```

Changing id's works fine, but my problem is that element with new id does not interact as the original element. This part of code should be part of code in svg-editor where every button with id has some funcionality. I need to implement 2 buttons with same funcionality on one page. But I can't have more than one element on page. It is really hard for me to implement other "id" to have same funcionality, because I can not well oriented in the code of svg-editor. So I thought that simply exchange id and my problem will be solved. But changed id does not interact. Exist any sollution to keep all properties and functionality of original id, when the id is changed ?

Comment: `'tool_fhpath2'` Can you show the event binding for this element.

Comment: I dont know for sure but you can try with jquery clone. Thing is changing ids won't affect your new element